# Swap processors?

Tags: laptop, cpu, desktop, amd-ryzen

I have a couple of new laptops but this were smashed to bits (sadly) and rendered the systems unusable.
So, since the sockets of the ryzen are AM4(Picasso), isn't supposed (at least theoretically) to make a swap from the lap on to a desktop motherboard?
In order to rescue the processors.

Comment: Mobile processors are incompatible with desktop systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryzen mobile processors are soldered to the mainboard, they aren't socketed like their desktop variants, so a replacement isn't possible.